# How to get VSTest to use ServerGC without changing the app.config (.NET framework)?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, app-config, csproj, vstest

I have a .NET 4.7.1 C# class library with some associated tests in a separate project.
I would like to be able to run the tests in ServerGC mode to replicate the standard usage of the class library by consumers (both for normal and performance-related tests).

As per Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector) it is possible to configure ServerGC in a number of ways.
The runtimeconfig.json isn't an option because this is a .NET Framework project.

After some playing around with regular projects and tests projects. It appears to be the case that ServerGC must be set for whatever the parent process is for it to take effect. In the case of a regular application this is fine and makes it trivial to use the MSBuild property `ServerGarbageCollection` or the app.config file. In the case of running a project via VSTest, this makes the test runner (vstest.console.exe) the parent process which therefore means that the `ServerGarbageCollection` property has no effect. I would prefer not to have to change the app.config for vstest.console.exe because it is used by all test runs on that machine and could therefore interfere with other solutions.

The Microsoft documentation suggests that it is possible to set the environment variable: `COMPlus_gcServer` with a value of 1 to enable ServerGC. It is possible to set environment variables for VSTest in the runsettings file as shown by the example below and at the bottom of the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019). The documentation also states that specifying an environment variable will enforce the `/InIsolation` flag to ensure that the environment variables are set and then the test run process is started. However this doesn't appear to work.

```
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    <EnvironmentVariables>
      <COMPlus_gcServer>1</COMPlus_gcServer>
    </EnvironmentVariables>
  </RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

I have added a simple test case which checks the `GCSettings.IsServerGC` property and still gives false despite the environment variable being successfully read as having a value of 1 within the same test.

Edit: Having done more reading, it looks like the runtimeconfig.json property, the MSBuild property and the Environment variable are all .NETCore only. This leaves the only option as somehow providing VSTest with an app.config that contains the `GCServer` property. Is there any way to do this via runsettings or command line arguments to VSTest?